# Javascript update Object attribute value

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I´m trying to update the object atribute:

```
   data : [
     {"id":1,"rp":"2426","cr":"11-11"},
     {"id":1,"rp":"1119","cr":"19-21"},
     {"id":1,"rp":"3453","cr":"23-81"}
    ]
```

new object would be updated as below.

```
NewData: [
 {"id":1,"rp":"2426","cr":"11/11"},
 {"id":1,"rp":"1119","cr":"19/21"},
 {"id":1,"rp":"3453","cr":"23/81"}
]
```

I looking to update the object cr atribute for all values, for example using javascript.replace() method, I would do replace("-","/").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` method to create new array and `replace` to update `cr` property.

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"rp":"2426","cr":"11-11"},{"id":1,"rp":"1119","cr":"19-21"},{"id":1,"rp":"3453","cr":"23-81"}]
var update = data.map(({cr, ...rest}) => ({...rest, cr: cr.replace("-","/")}))
console.log(update)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just a simple usage of `Array#map` and `String#replace`:

**ES2018**

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"rp":"2426","cr":"11-11"},{"id":1,"rp":"1119","cr":"19-21"},{"id":1,"rp":"3453","cr":"23-81"}]

const r = data.map(({ cr, ...rest }) => ({ cr: cr.replace('-', '/'), ...rest }));

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting that rest/spread properties are part of ES2018, not ES2015.

Comment: Now it looks like you claim your solution can be used with ES2015 and ES2016. But as I said, object rest/spread is ES2018.

Comment: @FelixKling As you wish

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate and map the array.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, rp: "2426", cr: "11-11" }, { id: 1, rp: "1119", cr: "19-21" }, { id: 1, rp: "3453", cr: "23-81" }],
    newArray = data.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { cr: o.cr.replace("-","/") }));

console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const data = [
  {"id":1,"rp":"2426","cr":"11-11"},
  {"id":1,"rp":"1119","cr":"19-21"},
  {"id":1,"rp":"3453","cr":"23-81"}
];

const newData = data.map(item => ({...item, cr: item.cr.replace(/-/g, '/')}));

console.log(newData);
```

If you need it to work in IE11:

```js
const data = [
  {"id":1,"rp":"2426","cr":"11-11"},
  {"id":1,"rp":"1119","cr":"19-21"},
  {"id":1,"rp":"3453","cr":"23-81"}
];

const newData = data.map(
  function(item) {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      rp: item.rp,
      cr: item.cr.replace(/-/g, '/')
    }
  }
);

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: This looks as if it would be pure, but it actually isnt.

Comment: Updated to not affect original obj

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
let data = [
     {"id":1,"rp":"2426","cr":"11-11"},
     {"id":1,"rp":"1119","cr":"19-21"},
     {"id":1,"rp":"3453","cr":"23-81"}
    ];
    
    
let newData = data.map(e=>{
  e.cr = e.cr.replace(/-/, '/')
  return e
})

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below

```
data.forEach(function(object){
    object["cr"] = object["cr"].replace("-","/");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"rp":"2426","cr":"11-11"},{"id":1,"rp":"1119","cr":"19-21"},{"id":1,"rp":"3453","cr":"23-81"}]

const r = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/-/g,'/'))
console.log(r);
```